# Is it reasonable to link to a third-party site for review?

Tags: discussion, third-party

I've got a class I'd like to get reviewed but it's 820 lines, and the project where it's hosted at is in a better format than a question code block, I think. You can open it in your editor of choice.

Is it acceptable to make a question where there is just 2 lines and one is a link to a project? In my case it's a Sourceforge page.